# Первый элемент ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Допустим у меня есть некий `ComboBox`, у которого будет задача не по назначению. 
Допустим первый элемент этого ComboBox должен быть всегда надпись "Выберите фильтры", при этом остальные элементы из себя представляют `CheckBox` и `TextBox`. Как данную затею можно реализовать? Может есть более удобный контрол из стандартных

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял вопрос. Можно сделать так:

1) Создаем в ресурсах коллекцию, которая привязана к вашим реальным данным:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyKey" Source="{Binding Path=MyData}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

2) Далее у `ComboBox` в качестве `ItemsSource` используем `CompositeCollection`, а так же задаем шаблон для `ComboBoxItem`. Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
       <CompositeCollection>
           <ComboBoxItem Content="Выберите фильтры" />
           <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey}}" />
       </CompositeCollection>
   </ComboBox.ItemsSource>

   <!-- Шаблон для элементов ComboBox -->
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял то так :

```
   <Style x:Key="Filter">
        <Setter Property="Control.FontSize" Value="1"/>
    </Style>
```

Текст "Выберите фильтры" сделайте минимальным, можно под цвет комбобокса.

```
    <ComboBox Margin="0,80,0,125" Style="{StaticResource Style}" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Выберите фильтры" Style="{StaticResource Filter}">
        </ComboBoxItem>

        <ComboBoxItem>
            <CheckBox Content="Выберите" Width="525"/> <- Ставьте ширину не менее ширины самого бокса и тогда событие `IsSelected` никогда не наступит для элемента комбобокса но наступид для чек бокса 
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <TextBox Text="Текст" Width="525"/>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Все ComboBox которые идут после первого являются полностью кастомными, по идее на первый можно повесить Style = {x:Null}

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Что значит первый, у вас несколько `ComboBox ` ?

Comment: очепятка, ComboBoxItem

Comment: @ParanoidPanda можно. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Как можно так закастамизировать combobox, что его элементы не имеют проперти IsSelected, у нас просто ComboBox который имеет в себе первый элемент, который всегда показывается - "Выберите фильтр" а остальные элементы в себе имеют чекбоксы для выбора

Comment: @ParanoidPanda ага, вроде понял. минуту

Comment: @ParanoidPanda поправил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Combobox вряд ли то что вам нужно. Посмотрите этот вариант:

```
<Expander Header="Выберите фильтры" Grid.Row="1" Width="135" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Expander>
```